# zip function python - weird behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any explanation for what is happening below?

```
>>> foo = [10, 20]
>>> bar = [30, 40]
>>> foobar = zip(foo, bar)

>>> list(foobar)
[(10, 30), (20, 40)]

>>> tuple(foobar)
()

>>> list(foobar)
[]

>>> foobar
<zip object at 0x000001198D28E280>
```

Although `foobar` is still a zip object, why these outputs?

Comment: You depleted the iterator with your first line, now there is nothing left to convert to tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and returns an iterator. Once it's finished yielding that's that.

```py
def mygen():
  count = 10
  while count:
    yield count
    count -= 1

gen_obj = mygen()

print(list(gen_obj))
print(list(gen_obj))
# [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# []
```

Comment: `zip` objects arent actually generators, but they are iterators

Comment: I believe it actually is a generator. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip I guess I am getting mixed up on the terminology. A generator returns an iterable?

Comment: From your link: "`zip(*iterables)`: Make an ***iterator*** that aggregates elements from each of the iterables"

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: @DragonBobZ no, they are not generators. All generators are iterators, but not all iterators are generators. Anything that you can iterate over is an *iterable*, including iterators, basically, anything that has an `__iter__` method is iterable. This must return an interator, which itself has an `__iter__` method (that simply returns `self`) and a `__next__` method, which is what produces the next item

Comment: I don't want to claim I am 100% on this, but [my understanding](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/yield.html) is that using `yield` in the body of a function makes that function a generator. And since [`zip` is implemented with `yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), that would make `zip` a generator which returns an iterable.

Comment: Confusingly, I believe the returned iterable is actually also referred to as a generator (from the docs linked in previous comment): "When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator iterator, or more commonly, a generator. The body of the generator function is executed by calling the generator's next() method repeatedly until it raises an exception."